# How to increase the resoltuion of a 20 khz pwm Wave (Atmega 328p)?

Tags: atmel, atmel-studio, atmega328p

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL 
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

double dutycycle = 0 ;

#include <avr/io.h>

int main(void)
{
DDRB = 0xFF;
TCCR1A |= _BV(COM1A1) | _BV(COM1B1);
TCCR1B |= _BV(WGM13) | _BV(CS11);//PRESCALER=64 MODE 14(FAST PWM)


ICR1=50;

OCR1A = 25;

while (1)
{       
}
}
```

With this code i have been able to generate a PWM wave of 20 khz but the resolution is very low is there a way to increase the resolution of the wave ?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean by "resolution" that you need to have more than 8 bits, you will need to use your other timer/counter (the ATmega328 has one with 16bits). To get 12 bits of resolution you would need to do the following:

- Use TC1
- Set a lower prescaler to enable faster counting, roughly a factor of 8 should be fine
- Set an upper value of e.g. 4096 (=2^12 bit), this is the value where the counter shall reset
- Set a threshold/OCR value of a value between 0 and 4096, this is your output value